# If G contains a normal subgroup $N \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $G/N \cong \mathbb{Z}$, then $G\cong \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z_2}$.

Tags: group-theory

If G contains a normal subgroup $N \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $G/N \cong \mathbb{Z}$, then $G\cong \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z_2}$.

I'm trying to create an isomorphism $\phi : G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$ as $g \mapsto (gN, ??)$. What can I use for my second coordinate?

Comment: Please put the entire setup in the question body, rather than leaving part of it in the title.

Comment: Hint: $G$ clearly has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ which intersects the subgroup of order $2$ trivially. Now use for example that in fact the subgroup of order $2$ must be central as it is normal of order $2$.

Answer (score 1):

First, we should show that $G$ is abelian:

$N=\{e,n\}$ is a normal subgroup with two elements, in particular $n$ is a central element.

$G/N$ is cyclic, let $g \in G$, such that $\overline g$ is a generator. Then any $x \in G$ is of the form $g^jn$ with some $j \in \mathbb Z$. Since $n$ is central, two elements of the form $g^jn$ certainly commute with each other.

Now we are given a short exact sequence of abelian groups

$$0 \to C_2 \to G \to \mathbb Z \to 0$$

Since $\mathbb Z$ is free, the sequence splits, thus $G \cong C_2 \times \mathbb Z$.

Comment: 1) It is not true that every $x \in G$ ca be written as $g^j n$: think of $e$. What you mean is that $x$ can be written (uniquely) as $g^j n^a$ with $a \in \{0,1\}$. 2) Establishing this representation for the elements of $G$, itself requires a proof, since it is essentially the core of the problem. You state it as if it were some minor point of the whole construction, but I believe that it should be given more attention.

Comment: This is just the application of basic knowledge of equivalence relations, isn't it? I have never claimed that any of my answers cover any single detail. But saying this particular aspect is a key step seems pretty subjective to me.

Comment: Well, it seems that this was not that basic for the OP. Remember that we are not here to judge the others' abilities with respect to ours, but rather to patiently help them improve their abilities.

Comment: You got a point there. I would be glad to cover this aspect if the OP would have asked.